# What is a Data SMS?

Tags: sms

Android phones seem to support 2 kinds of SMS: Text SMS and Data SMS. I think I know what a text SMS is, but what is a Data SMS and how / for what is it used (btw as far as I can tell Data SMS are not MMS)?

I recognize that this might not be Android specific, but I encountered the term first on my Android handset, so here I go. If this is more general and better moved to a different forum feel free to suggest so...

Comment: I don't seem to find this on my android device. Can you tell the version of your android/model of the phone? Or include the screenshot if you can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data SMS messages are sent through the data network, over your 2G / 3G data connection, just like all other data such as internet traffic.  Normally SMS messages have their own method of transport, the details of which you can check out [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Technical_details).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gets me half way there, but I still don't understand what it is used for. If you can add an example of a real-world service/application that sends data SMS or a common use-case I'll tick your answer.

Comment: @user4188 Data SMSes cost much less...

Comment: Its more reliable, too..

Answer (score 4):

A perfect example for data SMS use is when your recipient must pay to receive your text message even though you may have unlimited texting.  By using a data SMS service, all extra charges are avoided and the amount of data used by SMS messages is insignificant compared to even lite web page viewing.

Answer (score 4):

I think Data SMS messages are sent not only through the data network (over your 2G / 3G data connection), but also through GSM as Text SMS. The PDU of a text message has a User Data Headers (UDH) that defines a specific port on a handset. Refer to this link: http://developers.esendex.com/Concepts-and-Patterns/Sending-SMS-to-a-Specific-Port

Answer (score 2):

User named `www.jensolsson.se` is correct. OP is also correct it's not really a Android subject perse, it's more of a cellular technology subject. Since we are not sticking to Android is will share my experience with data sms in the Linux side of things. I use data sms for a custom IoT type of communication to do very low level control of the devices such as rebooting or restarting a misbehaving application. I use the mmcli tool to send and receive the data sms messages. The data value that I send is a bitmasked binary value (from memory a 64bit value) that represents the operational status of the device and its applications. A good place to start is looking at the mmcli man page. I learned of this capability while learning how to use mmcli to send and receive text messages using mmcli. My text messages were becoming giant JSON strings. Since I controlled both ends, I developed a custom protocol that only needs a single 64bit symbol with many values encoded in to it.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/latest/mmcli.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Data SMS is just like regular SMS. Contrary to what other answers to this question which implies the data smses dont use the 3g/4g data connection at all. You can actually disable both mobile data and wifi on your phone and you can still send and receive data sms.

Data SMS is a feature for app to app communication. Historically it was also used for example to change certain aspects of the phone. For example adding operator logo, ring tones etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As it contradicts other answers and I have no way of telling who is right, could you back up your answer with references that support it?

Comment: You could check wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header